# Redmi Note 4. ADB pm uninstall some packages, Stuck in Reboot

Tags: adb, 7.0-nougat, 7.1-nougat, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g, redmi

So I wanted to remove some apps pre installed.

I connected to my `Redmi Note 4 ( Nougat )` via `adb shell`.

Used `pm uninstall -k --user 0 <name of package>`

Removed the following packages.

```
com.android.browser
com.android.email
com.google.android.apps.tachyon
com.google.android.music
com.google.android.play.games
com.google.android.videos
com.miui.cleanmaster
com.miui.cloudservice
com.miui.cloudservice.sysbase
com.miui.securitycenter
com.miui.weather2
com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad
com.xiaomi.mipicks
com.xiaomi.oversea.ecom
org.wordpress.android
```

According to me, I did not remove any system apps.
However now when I Reboot I am **stuck at Reboot Screen (bootloop)** with `adb devices` showing as `connecting`

I am able to boot into **fastboot** mode. Dont know how to make use of that here. Also I have a Ubuntu machine, so I am not able to use official MI tools which are mostly for Window users

Comment: You can't get to adb to enable anything again, so your only choice is going to be a factory reset unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have a custom recovery installed on that device, e.g. TWRP? Not sure if it works when running from there, but TWRP offers ADB access.

Comment: @Izzy No I do not have any custom recovery installed :/ ADB does connect though occassionally. Then it goes into connecting state again. When I was able to connect I tried doing adh shell pm install, but that gave me package service not  found error.

Comment: @acejavelin  ADB does connect though occassionally. Then it goes into connecting state again. When I was able to connect I tried doing adh shell pm install, but that gave me package service not  found error. Want to make sure FR is the last option I got

Comment: `pm install` needs the name of the *APK file,* not the package name. So you'ld need to know where that resides (most likely somewhere below `/system/app`), then pass the full file name (e.g. `/system/app/Music2/Music2.apk` for `com.google.android.music` on a device I just checked) to `pm install`.

Comment: thanks @Izzy . yeah I did give the /data/app location of APK. But it was not able to find the service 'Package'

Answer (score 0):

Flash a fastboot stock rom, fastboot rom even has a option to flash without wipe.

If you have a linux i could guide you further on how to do that.

Comment: It would help if you tell us how to flash a fastboot ROM.

Comment: Okay for starters the fastboot file has a .tgz format while the recovery rom has .zip . You'll have to extract the tgz file and select the .sh script which says to flash only /system and run the sh script.